# Android eclipse error TextView and EditView

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My name is Marek.
I'm from Poland.

I have problem with my project.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast andoid.widget.EditView
```

It's not working on Virtual Device and my devices

It's simple project for my learning development.

Sorry for my english.

java:

```
cylindr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cylindr);
    na = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.na);
    litry = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.litry);
    spalanie = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spalanie);
    obrot = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.obrot);
    ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ok);
    cylindr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cylindr);
    obroty = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.obroty);
    paliwo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.paliwo);
```

xml:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spalanie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/paliwo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/Spalanie" />


       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/paliwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spalanie"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:labelFor="@+id/paliwo"
        android:singleLine="true" />

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/litry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/paliwo"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/paliwo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/paliwo"
        android:text="@string/litrow" />
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/obrot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/paliwo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/paliwo"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/obroty" />
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/obroty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/obrot"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/litry"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:labelFor="@id/obroty" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/na"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/obroty"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/obroty"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/obroty"
        android:text="@string/na" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cylindr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/obrot"
        android:layout_below="@+id/obroty"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="@string/cylindry" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cylindry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cylindr"
        android:layout_below="@+id/obroty"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:labelFor="@id/cylindry" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dalej"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cylindry"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spalanie"
        android:text="@string/ok" />  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me!

Comment: You cannot both `(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cylindr)` and `(EditText)findViewById(R.id.cylindr)`. Which type is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cylindr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cylindr);
```

Should be:

```
cylindr = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cylindry);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently using `R.id.cylindr` twice, along with a duplicate variable.  You should use:

```
cylindr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cylindr);
na = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.na);
litry = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.litry);
spalanie = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spalanie);
obrot = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.obrot);
ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ok);
cylindry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cylindry); //this is the line that was wrong
obroty = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.obroty);
paliwo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.paliwo);
```

Comment: Good to hear, and welcome to SO!  If your question has been answered, please [accept an answer as such](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  Also, as a new user feel free to [take a tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more!